# ¿Cual es la diferencia Git Flow y Github Flow?

Tags: git

He estado leyendo, desde hace algún tiempo se que existe **Git flows**. Este flujo lo entiendo mas o menos bien, pero ahora me he enterado de que **Github flow** no es igual al flujo anterior . Se que Git flows propone las ramas master (production), develop, features/*, hotfix/* y release. He entrado en la guía de [Github flows](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) pero no he entendido del todo como funciona.

Me preguntaba cual es la diferencia entre ambos o en efecto ¿que es github flows?, he visto que hay muchos artículos en inglés, pero nada en español.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git-flow es un proceso para gestionar los cambios en Git que fue creado por Vincent Driessen y acompañado de algunas extensiones de Git para gestionar ese flujo.

La idea general detrás de git-flow es tener varias ramas separadas que siempre existen, cada una con un propósito diferente: master, develop, feature, release y hotfix.

El proceso de desarrollo de características o bugs fluye de una rama a otra antes de ser finalmente liberado.

Algunos de los encuestados indicaron que usan git-flow en general.
Algunos comenzaron con git-flow y se alejaron de ella.

La principal razón para alejarse es que el proceso git-flow es difícil de manejar en un modelo de despliegue continuo (o casi continuo).
La sensación general es que el git-flow funciona bien para los productos en un modelo de lanzamiento más tradicional, donde los lanzamientos se hacen una vez cada pocas semanas, pero que este proceso se descompone considerablemente cuando se está liberando una vez al día o más.

Comienzas con un modelo lo más simple posible (como GitHub-flow tiende ser), y avanzar hacia un modelo más complejo si es necesario.

Puedes ver una interesante ilustración de un flujo de trabajo simple, basado en GitHub-Flow en:
"Un simple modelo de ramificación git", con los elementos principales siendo:

1. Master debe ser siempre desplegable.
2. Todos los cambios realizados a través de las ramas de características (pull-request + merge)
3. "rebase" para evitar / resolver conflictos; unir para master [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6):

La sencillez.

#### git-flow

En git-flow se gestionan varias ramas con objetivos diferentes, por ejemplo, hay una rama de desarrollo, una *release*, una o varias ramas para características, para parches, etc.

El flujo indica que se empieza en una o varias feature, luego pasa a develop, luego a master y luego a release.

```
feature -> develop -> master -> release
```

Cada etapa de este ciclo lleva el mismo proceso de solicitud de fusión (*pull request*), de fusión (*merge*) **con la rama inmediata siguiente**.

Esto significa que cuando una *feature* está lista, se fusiona con la rama de desarrollo. Una vez que están listas todas las características deseadas para una versión (por ejemplo), la rama de desarrollo se fusiona con la master. Al final se libera una nueva versión en la rama *release*.

#### GitHub flow

En GitHub hay un *principio* sobre la rama master que dice: **la rama master *siempre* funciona**.

Además, hace uso de *tags* (un punto específico en alguna rama) y de una característica de *release* que es una instantánea de la *tag* selecciona, que permite crear estas *release* fácilmente.

Aunque el proceso de solicitud -> revisión -> fusión existe en GitHub Flow es más simple, porque no pasan por ramas consecutivas de desarrollo.

GitHub propone que todas las ramas de desarrollo vayan a *master* una vez aprobada y que la liberación de versiones se haga por medio de *tags* e instantáneas *release*.

> Por supuesto, ambos sistemas son opcionales. En mi opinión el GitHub flow funciona mejor para equipos pequeños o desarrolladores individuales. GF me parece más profesional, pero también más complicado.